# Defining the area under an oscillating function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I was curious about taking a definite integral of an oscillating function.

For example,

$$\lim_{a\to 0} \int_a^1 \sin \frac1x\,dx$$

I know that there is some area under the function, but since it oscillates infinitely is it possible to define it? Do you use the limit superior and the limit inferior? I know it is probably possible (somehow) to take the antiderivative, FTC, etc. but I am wondering what this really intuitively means, given that this function oscillates (so we can't really "see" the area under the function).

Comment: It's Riemann-integrable if and only if it's continuous almost everywhere, and this function certainly is, and even if it were not Riemann-integrable, there's no reason not to regard it as a Lebesgue integral. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

Using the substitution $x\mapsto1/x$, we get
$$
\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_a^1\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
=\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
which converges absolutely since
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=1
$$
The integral above computes the area below the curve above the $x$-axis and subtracts the area above the curve below the $x$-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After robjohn's answer, using special functions $$I=\int \sin\left(\frac 1x\right)~dx=x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\text{Ci}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ where appears the cosine integral. So,$$J=\int_a^1 \sin\left(\frac 1x\right)~dx=\text{Ci}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)-a \sin \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)-\text{Ci}(1)+\sin
   (1)$$ and $$\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_a^1\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
=\sin (1)-\text{Ci}(1)\approx 0.5040670619$$